# Why are flutter firestore queries really slow after some time without activity

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On flutter, when the app has not done any queries in some time (maybe 2 o more minutes), making a new query will take up to 10 seconds to be completed.

After that slow query, query speed normalize but the problem repeats again after some inactivity.

This is a problem with a larger app my team was developing. But I created a new app from zero just to make sure the problem is in our app itself but the same problem is happening on this new/simple application.

I am using the next packages versions:

- cloud_firestore: ^4.8.1
- firebase_core: ^2.14.0

This is the info i receive after executing "flutter --version"

```
Flutter 3.7.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2ad6cd72c0 (3 months ago) • 2023-03-08 09:41:59 -0800
Engine • revision 1837b5be5f
Tools • Dart 2.19.4 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

Here is the link for my test app repo:
https://github.com/LuisRococo/firestore-service-test