# Firebase abnormally slow? (Flutter + Firebase)

Tags: flutter, firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a flutter app that my team built for a store, everything was going fine until the three apps start running abnormally slow,

The app runs perfectly fine but when you don't use it for 5-10 minutes or if you lock the screen and then turn it on, it becomes slow.

I'm using the latest version of flutter and updated the libraries in all the apps to no avail.

Also, I'm on blaze plan and have never exceeded the limit yet.

What could it be?

e.g
https://github.com/LuisRococo/firestore-service-test

Comment: There are currently no known performance issues or outages with Firestore/Firebase that could explain this. This makes it impossible to troubleshoot without a [minimal repro and debugging details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502011/why-are-flutter-firestore-queries-really-slow-after-some-time-without-activity

This one is also having trouble with it, but this is the repo with the example
https://github.com/LuisRococo/firestore-service-test